# How to design a drawing App with MVC architecture?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a drawing application using AS3 and Starling Framework. The app will support multiple layers.

I'm also trying to design it based on Model View Controller.

My question is: should the Layer object be part of the model or the view?

Makes sense to have an array with layers in a model as a representation of what's in the canvas.
But also makes sense to have a Canvas or Container with Layer Children on the view.

Where should it go, on model or view?
Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

MVC is just a design pattern – not law. You should do what makes sense to you.

Personally, I would treat any code/object which deals with drawing (graphics.beginFill, etc) as a View. The data it draws is from a Model.

MVC is not monolithic: you can have many nested MVC constructions, so a "Layer" could be composed of a Model (perhaps references an instance contained in a larger "Document Model), a Layer Controller, and a Layer View.

Diagram it out: the various responsibilities and capabilities.

Comment: Thanks tomato, this was helpful.
Now my canvas and layers are just that, canvas and layers, and the model and view have references to them.